# MacPorts infinite loop error

Tags: macos, macports

I have recently installed MacPorts. Whenever I try to install anything, however, I get an error of the following format:

```
m2214:~ speyer$ sudo port install xfig
Password:
--->  Computing dependencies for xfigError: Internal error: port lookup failed: too many nested evaluations (infinite loop?)
Error: Status 1 encountered during processing.
To report a bug, see <http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets>
```

There is a substantial time delay between when "--> Computing dependencies for xfig" prints and the rest of the message.

Any suggestions? Google searching on the error message finds a lot of bug reports and complaints, but no fixes.

System Details:

MacPorts Version: 1.9.1

OS.X 10.6.4 Intel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running the `deps` command to see if MacPorts will compute the dependents at all:

```
% port deps pstoedit
```

On my system (OS X 10.5) I get the following output from that command:

```
% port deps pstoedit
Full Name: pstoedit @3.45
Runtime Dependencies: ghostscript
Library Dependencies: ImageMagick, plotutils, libpng, zlib
```

You could try installing the dependencies you generate via the `deps` command, or any of this list to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks! deps responds as described, and some of these install, while others produce the same error. So, I imagine I should be recursing and repeating?

Comment: How about `port rdeps xfig`? That should recursively look up all the dependencies. Does that work. Did you already do a `sudo port selfupdate` to make sure you have the most recent ports tree?

Comment: Spiff makes a good point - make sure you've run sudo port selfupdate recently, it might help to clear up a broken port which is causing the potential infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

This was most probably the recent bug caused by the xorg-libxcb Portfile. But a workaround has been applied. You should search on [MacPorts Trac](http://trac.macports.org) for such error messages first. [The ticket #26387](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/26387) tracks this problem and possible solutions.

From a user point of view, you don't need to do anything about this except updating your local Portfiles with this command:

```
sudo port selfupdate
```